# Passing UIImage to a function and Edit it externally

Tags: objective-c

Let's say we have this part of code for a UIView subclass:

```
self.myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"];

[self myFunc:self.myImage];
```

myFunc is here defined:

```
-(void)myFunc(UIImage*)img{
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
    [self addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Now i show in my view img1.jpg, if i decide to change self.myImage AFTER myFunc call

```
self.myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"];
```

why i continue to show img1 and not img2 ???  myFunc receive a UIImage pointer not directly an object... i'm pretty confused and i missed something really important i think.

Edit --

I'd like to have many UIImageView, and every image ivar of these view  must pointing to the same image address, changing image at this address every UIImageView have a new image how can i do that ? 
[image]

Comment: yeah, i think you missed how pointers work

Comment: uhm... maybe i'm tired :P could you give some more info on my error? thus, i hope i'll wake up

Comment: iOS cache graphic drawing. You might need to call -setNeedsDisplay. Better yet, you should have your UIImageView subscribe to the notification center. And when you update the UIImage post a notification. When the observers receives the notification, they call their own -setNeedsDisplay methods. This way you don't have to loop over all your UIImageView

Comment: +1: for your little graphic showing your problem. The more I look at it, the more I think you need to do [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

Comment: In the afternoon i'll try your solution (And sure i'll accept the answer) thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code.  Let say that when you load img1.jpg into memory it went to address 1000. And you use the ivar myImage to point to it. When you pass that ivar to your function and create the UIImageView it also points to img1.jpg.

Now, when you load img2.jpg into memory it went to a different address, for example 2000. And then updated the ivar myImage to point to that new location. img1.jpg is still in address 1000 and is still being used by the UIImageView.

If you want to change the image of the UIImageView you will have to use the image property of that class.

Comment: Ok ,thus, from `myImage` ivar i know that the image is at address 1000. What i can do to change THIS image directly from `myImage` ivar (and than change the image at which the UIImageView is pointing too) ?

Comment: I am thinking you would have to edit the image in memory. Let me check to see if there's a method for that.

Comment: uhm i think it's not possible because in obj-c i cant create static allocation (I.e. UIImage myNewImage = something instead of UIImage* )

Comment: I think you need to get the CGGraphicContext of the UIImage. It will take me a day or so to research.

Comment: Stop here :) this mean that the way i choose is not the best one.

Comment: I think I know what you want to do. You want hold a pointer to the current image that the view is displaying?

Comment: i edited the question take a look at the image i attached. 
I find a way to edit the image directly from the memory :
`*self.segment.separator.image = *img2;`
The problem is that nothing change :P

Answer (score 1):

The UIImage that you've given to the UIImageView does in fact not know itself the view it belongs to. It may be used in different views. You have to ask the UIImageView object for the current image that it displays. If you want to change the displayed image you would write:

```
self.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"];
```

Better you add a property for the UIImageView so that you can access it from everywhere in the class.

Comment: I try to explain in a better way where is my doubt: 
`self.myImage`initially points to an UIImage at memory address "N".
Calling `self.myFunc:self.myImage` i pass to `myFunc` the address "N" ?

Comment: i'm an idiot i understand now :P i'm really tired.. i go to bed :)